# Theory testing - beyond binary case

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given $n$ hypothesis $\{H_1, \dots, H_n\}$ which are mutually exclusive and exhaustive:

$$\forall_{i \neq j }P(H_iH_j) = 0\text{ and }\sum_{i=1}^nP(H_i)=1$$

Also we have acquired $m$ data points - $\{D_1,\dots,D_m\}$

It is common to assume logical independence of the data points given $H_i$ :

$$P(D_1\dots D_m\mid H_i) = \prod_{j=1}^mP(D_j\mid H_i)$$

Show that if we assume that:

$$P(D_1 \dots D_m\mid\overline{H_i}) = \prod_{j=1}^mP(D_j\mid\overline{H_i})$$

and $n>2$ then at most one of the factors $\frac{P(D_j\mid H_i)}{P(D_j\mid\overline{H_i})}$ is not $1$ for fixed hypothesis $H_i$.

Solution so far:
Using the Bayesian rule we can compute that: 
$$P(D \mid \overline{H_i}) = \frac{\sum_{k \neq i} P(D \mid H_k)P(H_k)}{\sum_{k \neq i} P(H_k)} = \frac{P(D) - P(D \mid H_i)P(H_i)}{1 - P(H_i)}$$

Substituting $D=D_1D_2 \dots D_m$ and using the first equation we get that:
$$P(D_1D_2 \dots D_m \mid \overline{H_i}) = \frac{P(D_1D_2 \dots D_m) - P(D_1D_2 \dots D_m \mid H_i)P(H_i)}{1 - P(H_i)} = \frac{\prod_{j=1}^mP(D_j) - P(H_i)\prod_{j=1}^mP(Dj \mid H_i)}{1 - P(H_i)}$$

Now substituting $d=D_j$ we can get that:
$$P(D_j \mid \overline{H_i}) = \frac{P(D_j) - P(D_j \mid H_i)P(H_i)}{1 - P(H_i)}$$

From this follows that
$$\prod_{j=1}^mP(D_j\mid\overline{H_i}) = \frac{\prod_{j=1}^m(P(D_j) - P(D_j \mid H_i)P(H_i))}{(1 - P(H_i))^m}$$

The ratios from the problem are
$$\frac{P(D_j\mid H_i)}{P(D_j\mid\overline{H_i})} = \frac{P(D_j\mid H_i)(1-P(H_i))}{P(D_j) - P(D_j \mid H_i)P(H_i)} = \frac{P(D_j\mid H_i)-P(D_j\mid H_i)P(H_i)}{P(D_j) - P(D_j \mid H_i)P(H_i)}$$

From which follows that such ration to be one is equivalent to 
$$P(D_j \mid H_i) = P(D_j)$$

Even so I can not seem to see how does the number of hypothesis play a role?

Comment: By $\overline{H_i}$ you mean the complement of $H_i$ in the union of $H_i$s?

Comment: Yes, so its equivalent to $H_1$ or $H_2$ or $\dots$ $H_n$ excluding $H_i$.

Comment: Would suggest looking at the $m=2,n=3$ case first as the simplest case. Perhaps something will come of writing out for instance $P(D_1 D_2 \overline{H_1}) = P(D_1 D_2 H_2) + P(D_1 D_2 H_3) = P(H_2) P(D_1 | H_2) P(D_2 | H_3) + P(H_3) P(D_1 | H_3) P(D_2 | H_3)$  ? 

 Also since you want to show at most one of those ratios is not 1, you can assume one of them is not 1, and try and see if the equations force the other ratio to be 1?

Comment: I've tried that, still the equation I get I can't find a way to prove what they want me to. IF you could show me the solution even in the case of 3 that would be great.

Comment: It is also interesting to see what goes wrong in $n=2$ case:  A trivial way to break this case is to have $D_1,D_2$ be independent given $H_1$, and then have the same events be impossible given $H_2$.  Generalizing this example to 3 hypotheses doesn't work. It really suggests an approach that involves mixing ratios for the different hypotheses.  I suppose one possible end goal is to show $(P(D_1 | H_1) - P(D_1 | \overline{H_1}))(P(D_2 | H_1) - P(D_2 | \overline{H_1})) = 0$ or something.

Comment: No, it doesn't brake at $n=2$, just in that case since $H_2 = \overline{H_1}$ then the two statements are true and do not produce this "interesting" behivour. At least thats how its stated from the authors.

Comment: Hmm? Consider two dart boards. Flip a coin to determine which dart board to throw at. Let $D_1$ be the event that you hit the top half of the first board, and $D_2$ be the event that you hit the left half of the first board. Now let $H_1$ be the event that you threw at the first board, and $H_2$ be the event that you threw at the second board. Computing the conditional probabilities, get conditional independence given both $H_1$ and $H_2$, yet both ratios are not $1$. (Note: $D_1,D_2$ are not independent themselves)

Comment: I'm gona give a concrete example from the book, to make it clear, cause. Consider that you have 12 machines, each producing same thing, 10 machines have 1/3 defective production, 1 has 1/5 and 1 has 1/2. Now you are given a unlabeled box of these with millions or infinite if you want, and you are trying to figure out which machines is it from. $H_1, H_2, H_3$ are the hyptohesis is it from the first 10, from the 11th or 12th machine. $D_1,D_2\dots,D_m$ are the first $m$ samples you take out. The author say if there are only 2 hyptohesis both of those 2 equalities hold, if more - only the first.

Comment: He left it for "simple" exercise to prove it and as a hint stated what have to be proven if we assume both, aka that from those ratios at most one is not 1, so for each hypthosis if the assumption was correct only 1 data point will contribute with information, which obviosly is wrong => so is the assumption.

Comment: PS. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121591/conditional-independence?rq=1  is the same question, but has no answer as well, and also a similarly nice motivation.

Answer (score 0):

$n=3$ case: 
So let's arrange in a table.

```
     H1    H2    H3
D1   a     b     c
D2   d     e     f
```

where for instance $a = P(D_1 | H_1)$.
Note that by Bayes' rule, to compute for instance
$P(D_1 | H_2+H_3)$, it's a weighted average of $P(D_1 | H_2)$ and $P(D_1 | H_3)$.

Then note that with $h_2 = P(H_2)$ and $h_3 = P(H_3)$,
$P(D_1 | H_2+H_3) = \frac{h_2}{h_2+h_3} b + \frac{h_3}{h_2+h_3} c$ and $P(D_2 | H_2+H_3) = \frac{h_2}{h_2+h_3} e + \frac{h_3}{h_2+h_3} f$
Both independence assumptions yield 
$(h_2+h_3)(h_2 be + h_3 cf) = (h_2 b + h_3 c)(h_2 e + h_3 f)$.
Simplifying yields that $cf+be = bf + ce$.
Note the assumption that $h_2$ and $h_3$ are strictly positive is needed here.

Now, studying this one equation yields that letting $t = e/(e+f)$,
$tb + (1-t)c = tc + (1-t)b$.

One can conclude that either $b=c$ or $e=f$ from this. This is clearly not complete, but wanted to mention that the motivation was to figure out what exactly the second independence assumption adds to the requirements.

**Edit:** (From chat)
Putting together everything:

1. $b=c$ or $e=f$,
2. $c=a$ or $d=f$,
3. $a=b$ or $d=e$.

All three of these are true, and the conclusion in this case is that either $a=b=c$ or $d=e=f$ (in which case, the ratio is $1$ for whichever row, as one is the average of the other two). Suppose $a=b$, so $d\neq e$ by the third condition. In the first condition, suppose that $b\neq c$ (otherwise $a=b=c$ already), so that $e=f$. Now in the second condition, $a \neq c$, so it must be that $d=f$, and $d=e=f$.
The full problem needs some more work, with more hypotheses.

---

Alright, here is an outline of the full situation:
Let $a_i = P(D_1 \mid H_i)$ and $b_i = P(D_2 \mid H_i)$

Also let $h_i = P(H_i)$.
Generalizing the 3 hypothesis case, we end up with equations of the form

$0 = \sum_{i<j,\ i\neq k,\ j\neq k} h_i h_j ( a_i b_j + a_j b_i - a_i b_i - a_j b_j)$

or

$0 = \sum_{i\neq k,\  j \neq k} h_i h_j ( a_i b_j - a_i b_i )$  for fixed $k$

Now, to generalize the goal of the 3 hypothesis case, we note the goal of showing that
$0 = (P(D_1 \mid H_1) - P(D_1 \mid \overline{H_1}))(P(D_2 \mid H_1) - P(D_2 \overline{H_1}))$

which can be expanded to showing that

$0 = \left( \sum_{j\neq 1} h_j (a_1 - a_j)\right)\left(\sum_{j \neq 1} h_j (b_1 - b_j)\right)
 = \sum_{i \neq 1,j \neq 1} h_i h_j (a_1 - a_i)(b_1 - b_j)$

Now if you expand, you study the summand $a_1b_1 - a_1 b_j - a_i b_1 - a_i b_j$, you will start to see very similar pieces to the other equations. Now you should have enough to finish. What will happen is that if you study the equations for $H_2,\ldots,H_n$, you will see $a_1 b_1 - a_j b_1 - a_1 b_j \sim -a_j b_j$ (summing). The equation for $H_1$ finishes the job.

Comment: Ok, something doesn't seem right here... Only used 2 data points and 2 hypotheses?

Comment: Oh, there's something sneaky here. If $H_2,H_3$ are the only hypotheses, I didn't assume that $D_1$ and $D_2$ are independent overall...

Comment: You should assume they are, give me a sec I'll look into it.

Comment: Thanks very much for the example it makes a few things clear. If I find a solution following this I'll accept it.

Comment: PS: You don't use 2 hypthosis, but three. Since the false statement is about $\overline{H_1} = H_2+H_3$ and anyway their sum is $1$ as you did you can forget about one of them.

Comment: I meant that to say there is no contradiction here. Now I see what you mean by the 2 machine case being uninteresting though. In any case, this shows something funny happens when you assume both conditional independence properties.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10097/discussion-between-evan-and-belov)